# How to download this source code?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I want to download the source code from here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib

I know I should do something like this on my Ubuntu 10.10 terminal:

```
git clone git://******.git
```

But I don't know the details. Where can I find the `git://******.git`?

Comment: Click on the "git readonly" button, it gives you the git url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its written on that Url itself: Click on `Git Read-only`

`git://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib.git`

Otherwise, if you don't intend to do further development, fork or contribute and just want to see the source code, you can also download as `.ZIP` or `.TAR.GZ` from the `Downloads` button.